# Localhost not accepting ssh tunnel connections from VM

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

On my local machine I have an SSH tunnel setup for postgres like so:

`ssh -fNL 5434:127.0.0.1:5432 user@host`

Then running `psql -h localhost --port 5434` works just fine and dandy, giving me a postgres terminal.

Then, on my VM (VirtualBox), I have the host `vmhost` defined as 192.168.56.1. SSHing into `vmhost` works fine- connects to the host.

But, running from the vm `psql -h vmhost --port 5434` yields:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "vmhost" (192.168.56.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5434?
```

Is there some kind of SSH tunnel forwarding magic thing that's not happening here? How can I allow this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `-g` option when opening the SSH connection.  Otherwise, only localhost itself can connect to the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ssh -fNL '*:5434:127.0.0.1:5432' user@host
```

Note the '*' used as the binding address.